# Select where Unknown multiple columns have a False value

Tags: python, mysql

With an allergies table 
   `| Recipes_id| is_dairy| is_nuts| is_meat| etc.|  etc.| etc.| 
 +-----------+---------+--------+--------+-----+------+-----+`
The user specifies only the things he doesn't want to have in it's recipe, e.g without nuts and dairy.
 Is there a way in mysql(8.0.1) to query without a predefined length of parameters? 
e.g `select from allergies where a = false and b = false and c = false`
 where the length (here a,b,c = 3) isn't known ahead?
 I'm using flask as my backend engine
Just for clarification, the number of variables is not predefined, e.g it can be 3 columns in one query, and 5 in the other (the number of columns need to be false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have `NULL`s in there, you could use `NOT IN` to check, that there is not `true` in the list of columns you want to check.

```
SELECT *
       FROM allergies
       WHERE true NOT IN (a,
                          b,
                          c);
```

If you have `NULL`s and they should be treated like `false` you can use `colaesce()`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM allergies
       WHERE true NOT IN (coalesce(a, false),
                          coalesce(b, false),
                          coalesce(c, false));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's clear to me, the thing is that the number of variables is not predefined, e.g it can be 3 columns in one query, and 5 in the other. I was hoping a "list like" syntax is available.

Comment: @DsCpp: I mean it like you can build a list of columns and put that in the query. The number of columns alone doesn't help you. Say you have two users, one allergic to nuts, the other lactose intolerant. They both will query filter for one column, but two different ones.

Comment: So for example for the coalesce(a, false) way I will generate the sting of all the checked allergies in python, and push it as %s to sql?